# How to extract multiple dates from varchar2(4000) multiline string using sql?

Tags: sql, regex, plsql, oracle11g

I have two columns `ID (NUMBER)`, `DESCRIPTION (VARCHAR2(4000))` in original table

`DESCRIPTION` column has multi line strings.

I need to extract dates from each line of the string and also need to find earliest date. so the result would look like in expected result table.

Origional result:
[image: Origional result]

Expected Table:
[image: Expected Table]
Using this query:

```
to_date((regexp_substr(A.Description , '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}')), 'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

I was able to extract date from the first line

```
Discontinued:09/10/2015:Rappaport Family Institute for Research:;
```

only, but not from the other two.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I found a solution similar to the other post, but simpler.  FYI. regexp_substr() function only returns one match. Here is an example with a string with embedded line feeds (really does not matter, but added to show it will work in this case):

```
  WITH A AS
  (SELECT 'this is a test:12/01/2015  01/05/2018'
    || chr(13)
    ||chr(10)
    || ' this is the 2nd line: 07/07/2017' Description
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT to_date(regexp_substr(A.Description , '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}',1,level),'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM A
  CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(a.description, '\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}')
```

Output:

```
12/01/2015
01/05/2018
07/07/2017
```

If you are not familiar with hierarchical queries in oracle, "level" is a pseudo-column.  By using that as the 3rd parameter (occurrence) in the regexp_substr function, each "level" will start the pattern match after the prior found substring.  regexp_count will count the #times the pattern is matched, so we keep parsing the sting, moving over one occurrence until the max #of matches is reached.